# Nuxt js : How to call a javascript function from a plugin in a component

Tags: nuxt.js

I use external resources, I would like to know how to call a function in a component

**from**

```
plugins: [ { src: '~plugins/custom.js', ssr: false } ]
```

**call to**

```
methods: { myfunction() { myJavascriptFunctionIntoCustomJS() }
```

**file custom.js** :

```
(function ($) {

'use strict';

 function myJavascriptFunctionIntoCustomJS(){ ... }
 function myOtherJavascriptFunctionIntoCustomJS(){ ... }
```

})

Comment: You dont need plugin for that, just export your function from any file and them import it

Comment: thank you for this information
I use a third-party bookseller designed with such functions (see the initial message)
but I think I can not access it without transforming the file :)

Comment: Yes, right, you cant